# How to toggle selectable of multiple objects?

Tags: selection-tools, select

How to toggle 'selectable' for multiple objects in outliner ? For example in outliner, if i select 50 objects, then pressing the 'selectable' button only turn on/off for current/single object. So how can i do it for multiple objects ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, you've already added 'Selectable' to your visible restriction toggles in the outliner.

- Create a new collection for the objects you want to make simultaneously selectable / non-selectable. Call it, say, 'S1'.
- Select the objects of interest in the 3D view or the outliner, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> link them to 'S1'. (It's a link, not a move, it won't screw up your existing organisation.)
- When you want to toggle the selectability of all the items linked in S1, Shift-click the dart icon next to the 'S1' folder.